# Octave read just one column from CSV - unknown range

Tags: csv, range, octave

I want to read CSV with many columns and I want to read just one of them. I found function [dlmread()](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#XREFdlmread).

"The first form of the parameter is a 4-element vector containing the upper left and lower right corners [R0,C0,R1,C1] where the indices are zero-based"

```
M = dlmread('/home/lukas/deetction/tile_16.csv,'\t', [2, 1,  unknown, 1])
```

Problem is I do not know how many rows there will be, it is different in each file. How could I define R1 to read as many rows as there is? The function is working if I define whole range [2,1,10,1], but how to define unknown R1 ?

Or have sholud I read CSV to get just one column with unknown number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GNU Octave 4.3.0+ (today the development version built from source and base for the 4.4 release) you can use `inf` for the unknown size (which is in contrast to the answer from Sardar).

This was changed [with this changeset on stable](http://hg.octave.org/octave/rev/31be59137160) and would be part of 4.2.2 bugfix release (if there is one..) or the next stable release 4.4.

Looks like this behaviour has changed from 4.0.3

```
% create sample data 5 rows, 3 columns
x = (1:3)+(10:10:50).'
csvwrite ("foo", x)
clear all
% read second column until end
dlmread ("foo", ",", [0 1 inf 1])
```

gives

```
x =

   11   12   13
   21   22   23
   31   32   33
   41   42   43
   51   52   53

ans =

   12
   22
   32
   42
   52
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

Use `NaN` for the unknown `R1`.

### Detailed Answer:

In **Octave**, the trick is to define the unknown `R1` to be `NaN` or `-inf` or any integer greater than or equal to the maximum number of rows including `inf`. i.e.

> ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍   ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  1  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ∈  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ {, -}  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ∪  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ [   , ]

If `C1` is not known, you can choose `C1` to be any integer value greater than the maximum number of columns (excluding `inf`).

<sup><sup>Thanks to [AndrasDeak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067311/andras-deak) for testing this in Octave 4.0.3.</sup></sup>

---

However in **MATLAB**, you can choose `R1` to be `NaN` or any integer value less than `R0` including `-inf` (or maximum number of rows which is unknown for your case though).

> ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍   ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  1  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ∈  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ {,    }  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ∪  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ [-, 0-1]

Note that this trick works for selecting `R1` only. You *cannot* choose `C1` in the same way.

---

Therefore, I would prefer `NaN` for the unknown `R1` to make the code compatible with both platforms and to avoid possible confusions.

Comment: The use of `NaN` or `-inf` will no longer work in GNU Octave >4.2.1. Use `inf` instead